# Remove specific key from get parameter in htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I am trying to remove a specific query parameter from my URL. In my case I would only like to remove the 
code=blahblah and do this in htaccess.

For example if my URL is 
http://www.foo.com/project/index.php/current-page?code=blahblah

I need it do become
http://www.foo.com/project/index.php/current-page

I do not want to get rid of all query parameters though eg.
http://www.foo.com/project/index.php/current-page?id=67&code=blahblah

I need it to become
http://www.foo.com/project/index.php/current-page?id=67

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule for removal of `code=blahblah` from anywhere in the query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?&)?code=blahblah(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX :

```
 (https?:\/\/[^?]*\??.*?)([&?]code=[^ &]*)(.*)
```

And replace with : `\1\3`

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yC5gU7)**

In **Htaccess** :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (https?:\/\/[^?]*\??.*?)([&?]code=[^ &]*)(.*) /$1$3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: do you know how can i used this in htaccess

Comment: I still cannot get this to work, do i need a rewrite condition?